# Email Approval Process On Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, email

Are there any tools out there that allow you to check a box (or something like that) and say that you want to subject a given email for approval.  Then, once the email is approved, it goes to the original intended recipient?

The idea would be that certain emails (but not all) require approval before being sent.  Absent a solution, people have to get emails approved and then forward email out to the original intend recipient.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at Send If Approved from MAPILab. It's an Outlook plugin

> [MAPILab - Send If Approved
>   Component](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/toolbox/send_if_approved.html)

Comment: Keep in mind if you go this route, that this is a client-side implementation of the functionality you want. A nefarious user on the client-side could bypass this fairly easily by breaking/disabling the plugin.

Comment: I will have to look into it. The fact they could disable it would not be the end of the world b/c it has to be an "honor system" to a certain extent.  they have to do get it approved either way and if there is something that makes it easier on them, I would imagine they would use it.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously not applicable to your current situation with 2003, but Exchange 2010 has a moderation feature.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297936.aspx).